# How to composite videos using multiple AVVideoCompositions

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, avfoundation, video-processing

I'm trying to figure out how to composite multiple videos `(AVAssets)` into a single video such that each of the videos goes through its own video composition. However, I can't see a way to accomplish this and was wondering if anyone had any ideas.

Consider the following:

[image]

The above picture illustrates what I'm trying to do. I want to take the video track from four different videos and merge them into a single video such that they play in a grid-like layout.

Right now, I'm able to achieve this by doing the following

- Create a single `AVMutableComposition`
- Add four video tracks to the mutable composition
- Create four `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` instances with the appropriate `transform` applied to scale and translate the track.
- Create an `AVMutableVideoComposition`, add the layer instructions to it and then set that video composition on the appropriate `AVAssetExportSession`

While this works, it doesn't offer me the ability to do any custom effects on each video track before compositing it into the output clip. For example, in the picture above I'd like to add a unique border color around each track. With a single video (and thus no layer instructions), then I can just add the border using something like `AVVideoComposition applyingCIFiltersWithHandler`, which works great. But I can't use that because I need the video composition for setting the transform and scale instructions.

(`applyingCIFiltersWithHandler` doesn't appear to offer a way to get access to the tracks that make up the frame being rendered.)

What I think I want is the ability to do some type of custom rendering within a `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction`, but the only options currently available are transform and opacity ones.

(Note that any solution requires that I have access to the current composition time during rendering *for each video track*  because some of the "effects" I'd like to render are a frame counter and a timecode display.)

Any help, ideas or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Kenny, I and my team are struggling for weeks on this issue. Any chance you solved it buddy?

Comment: As noted in the answer below, a custom compositor that implements the `AVVideoCompositing` protocol is the correct way to go. Once you have that, then you can do just about anything you want. In my case, I use Core Image to render whatever content I want to a `CVPixelBuffer`, and then just return that buffer in my custom compositors implementation of `startVideoCompositionRequest`. Since you only have to return a single buffer, you can pretty much composite whatever you want into that buffer, however you want.

Comment: Hey Kenny, thank you for replying! I sent you an email regarding this subject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement a custom compositor that implements the AVVideoCompositing protocol. https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avvideocompositing

The startRequest function within that protocol receives an https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avasynchronousvideocompositionrequest and this allows you to access the information from each track https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avasynchronousvideocompositionrequest/1390379-sourceframe, then combine them with your own custom instructions and composite (put them together) in your own way, returning a final single buffer that has the frame composited from the tracks in the way you like.

Comment: Thanks Tim, however I don't see where I can retrieve the current presentation time of each track from within `startVideoCompositionRequest`. I can retrieve the frame for a track via `sourceFrameByTrackID`, but it's returned as a `CVPixelBufferRef` and thus has no timing information. The only timing information that I see is the global composition time, which doesn't really tell me where in each source track the current frame comes from.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avasynchronousvideocompositionrequest The AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest contains a compositionTime property which is a CMTime that indicates the timestamp of the video the composition request is for.  What tracks are available at that time stamp depends on the Instructions you've set.

Comment: If you want to know the time relevant to the specific track, then just subtract the composition time from the track time you specified when building the video.

Comment: Getting the relevant time for each specific track is exactly what I want. It sounds like I'll have to manually create a dictionary that maps track IDs to time ranges when building the `AVMutableComposition'. Then, I need to build a custom `AVVideoCompositing` class and pass in that dictionary. From within `startVideoCompositionRequest`, I can extract a track by its ID, get its presentation timeRange from the dictionary, subtract the composition time from the timeRange's start time and then I'll have the effective presentation time of each frame being rendered.

Comment: Tim, your advice has led me towards an implementation that should work, thank you. However, I've hit upon one serious (looking) issue: When I set the `customVideoCompositorClass` on my `AVMutableVideoComposition` and then apply that (previously working) videoCompostion to an `AVAssetExportSession`, then I get a sandbox violation from the `VideoCompositionProcessor` (-12917). It looks like that process is attempting to request sandbox access to the export session's outputURL but fails because the file hasn't yet been created (this occurs on frame 0). Just removing the compositor fixes things.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped. I'm not familiar with the error you've raised, although I've never tried using the custom compositor with AVAssetExportSession, but rather a custom AVAssetReader / AVAssetWriter implementation.

Comment: Will do. For my own sanity, you've used a custom video compositor on an `AVAssetWriter` in a sandbox application and successfully exported a video? `AVAssetExportSession` is convenient but it's a bit of a black box, I might migrate over to `AVAssetWriter` anyways. Knowing that it works for you with a custom video compositor would be good.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sandbox application, but yes, we've definitely implemented Custom Compositors using AVAssetWriter / Reader.  If you mean using the simulator, we only ever really test on device because of the heavy camera integration we're typically doing.

Comment: Applications on macOS can either follow the iOS security model and be "sandboxed" or they can follow the older, macOS-only model and not be sandboxed. For iOS apps this is a moot point because they all have to be sandboxed, but many macOS applications (and APIs) have had a rough transition to a sandboxed world. [Apple Documentation: About App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html)

Comment: Thanks - that was interesting. Yeah, our app is definitely not sandboxed then, it's a Mac OSX private, internal app that runs as a Command Line Utility.