# iOS - Merge multiple videos applying CIFilter

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, cifilter

I want to merge two or more videos (stored on disk) in one file. It has worked great with `AVAssetExportSession`. But next problem is to apply different `CIFilter` for each video. For applying CIFilter for one video I've used `AVMutableVideoComposition(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)`
Is it possible to merge two (and mode) AVMutableVideoCompositions without saving each video with filter on disk separately? Or should I use `AVAssetReader/Writer` for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. However, it's a bit more complicated, unfortunately. And you need a lot more glue code.

You can fully customize how multiple videos are composed (and what happens to the single frames before) by implementing a custom compositor that implements the `AVVideoCompositing` protocol. There is an [old example project from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVCustomEdit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013411) showcasing the whole process. There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153013/how-to-composite-videos-using-multiple-avvideocompositions) and answer on StackOverflow that you can refer to.

The basic idea is that you implement your filter and composition logic in the [`startRequest(_:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocompositing/1388894-startrequest) of your custom compositor. There you'll have access to the frames of all input videos. So you can process and compose them to your liking.