# What is the best way to draw custom timestamp text over a video with AVFoundation?

Tags: avfoundation, avassetwriter, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

I've got an AVMutableVideoComposition that I'm exporting with AVAssetExportSession and I'm trying to overlay a custom timestamp that updates every second on top of it. Should I be using AVAssetWriter, multiple CALayers with CABasicAnimations, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you write your own custom compositor by implementing the `AVVideoCompositing` protocol. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40160919/541016) and check out [this (old) WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/612/).

Inside the `startRequest` method you can use Core Image to add the text overlay to the frame. You can generate a `CIImage` containing text using the [`CIAttributedTextImageGenerator`](https://cifilter.io/CIAttributedTextImageGenerator/) filter.